# Moodle iframe-resizer

Tags: iframe, moodle, iframe-resizer

This is my code on **Moodle (book)** and it's not working on **Anchor**:

```
<div id="iframe-container">
    <iframe id="myIframe" src="http://localhost/html/pluginfile.php/63/mod_resource/content/1/1.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>

<script src="http://localhost/html/pluginfile.php/63/mod_resource/content/1/iframeResizer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    iFrameResize({ 
        log: true, 
        inPageLinks: true,
    }, '#myIframe');
</script>


iFrameSizer][myIframe] Moving to in page link (#declare) at x: 8 y: 7775 iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:164:15
[iFrameSizer][myIframe] Sending message to host page (myIframe:7775:8:scrollToOffset) iframeResizer.contentWindow.js:164:15
[iFrameSizer][Host page: myIframe] Received: [iFrameSizer]myIframe:7775:8:scrollToOffset iframeResizer.js:144:20
[iFrameSizer][Host page: myIframe] Checking connection is from: http://localhost iframeResizer.js:144:20
[iFrameSizer][Host page: myIframe] Get page position: 0,0 iframeResizer.js:144:20
[iFrameSizer][Host page: myIframe] Reposition requested from iFrame (offset x:67 y:422) iframeResizer.js:144:20
[iFrameSizer][Host page: myIframe] Set page position: 75,8197 iframeResizer.js:144:20
[iFrameSizer][Host page: myIframe] -- iframeResizer.js:144:20
```

And outside scroll (html) didn't work on href (anchor).
When I click on href (anchor) - nothing happened.

The problem is simillar to:
http://firedictionary.com/test/parent.html.
In this link there is problem in FF (like in my case), but I have this isue in all browsers.

I expect href (anchor) to work.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Your code and the log output looks good to me. There must be something else on the page blocking the scrolling. You might try creating you own `onScroll` method and explore what happens when you use that to try and move the page.

Comment: The scroll is ok. The only problem is with href(anchor) and clicking on it. It cause no effect at all when I clicking on it (link) with href to the anchor.

Comment: What effect are you expecting?

Comment: The problem is simillar to: http://firedictionary.com/test/parent.html, 
but in this example it doesn't matter what browser is.

Comment: In above link there is problem in FF (like in my case), but I have this isue in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
// aby zadziałał skrol
#page-wrapper {
height: auto;
}
```

and magically scroll moving, but on whole page and I must add:

```
// aby poprawić błąd skrola
onScroll: function (coords) {
                window.scrollTo(coords.x, coords.y-130);
                return false;
            }
    });
```